# I can't delete file using SHFileOperation

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I want to delete a file into recycle bin. I using this code.

```
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT FileOp;
    FileOp.hwnd = NULL;
    FileOp.wFunc=FO_DELETE; 
    FileOp.pFrom= lpFileName; //it's my value  \\?\C:\WorkFolder\qweqw.docx
    FileOp.pTo = NULL;
    FileOp.fFlags=FOF_ALLOWUNDO|FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
    FileOp.hNameMappings=NULL;      
    int t_res = SHFileOperation(&FileOp); // t_res = 124
    return t_res;
```

What's i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what error you received?What does t_res contains? What does call to GetLastError() return? try and share with us.

Comment: Error = 124 (ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL)

Comment: @Sasha Please update your question with that extra information.

Comment: @Sasha, Deanna: 124 there is not `ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL`, it is `DE_INVALIDFILES` instead (see unwind's below).

Comment: The \\?\ format is supported for API functions, but I wouldn't necessarily expect it to work for Shell functions such as SHFileOperation.  Try passing it a normal path, c:\WorkFolder\qweqw.docx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is `t_res`, it should give the error code and suggest the reason
2. Note that `pFrom` takes files, not single file, so you should terminate the buffer with two zeros, see [doc excerpt from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Although this member is declared as a single null-terminated string,
>   it is actually a buffer that can hold multiple null-delimited file
>   names. Each file name is terminated by a single NULL character. The
>   last file name is terminated with a double NULL character ("\0\0") to
>   indicate the end of the buffer.

Comment: 1. i add comment near t_res error = 124. 2. I added \0\0 and error the same.

Comment: My guess would be that it sees your first file, then you don't do termination with extra zero character, it keeps parsing to get second file name, it is not a valid name and hence the error. I suggest that you check the memory in debugger, whether you are sending the data you think should be there. Incorrect file name is the most likely thing you have.

Answer (score 0):

The error code is, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> DE_INVALIDFILES   0x7C    The path in the source or destination or both was invalid.

You don't mention any analysis of this, so my suggestion would be to dig into how the filename is represented. Is it the proper encoding?